# SQL Calculating time/date in query example

Tags: mysql, sql

Database schema consists of:

1. Company(ID_comp, name)
2. Trip(trip_no, id_comp, plane, town_from, town_to, time_out, time_in)
3. Pass_in_trip(trip_no, date, ID_psg, place)

Company table has ID and name of the company, which transports passengers. Trip table has information about trips: trip number, company ID, plane type, departure city, arrival city, departure time, and arrival time. Pass_in_trip table has information about the flights: trip number, departure date (day), passenger's ID and his place during the flight. We should note that,
- Any trip is being accomplished every day; duration of a flight is less than a calendar-day (24 hours); town_from <> town_to;
- Time and date are considered comparatively one time zone;
- The departure time and the arrival time are given to within a minute;

Q: For each company, find time the company's planes have spent during accomplished flights. Result set: company name, time in minutes.

A:

```
select Z.name,
sum ( 
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(mi,time_out,time_in) <0
THEN DATEDIFF(mi,time_out,time_in) + 1440
ELSE DATEDIFF(mi,time_out,time_in)
END) as minutes
from (

  select distinct C.name,T.trip_no,    DATE   ,time_out,time_in  
  from Pass_in_trip as Pt
  JOIN Trip as T
  ON T.trip_no=Pt.trip_no
  JOIN Company as C
  ON C.ID_comp = T.ID_comp
) Z
group by Z.name
```

Can anyone tell me how the date variable effects the query, I dont see how it is important. However, WHen you try to remove the date variable in the (main query) FROM statement, the output is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a difference because you use `SELECT DISTINCT`. If you have two rows with the same `name, trip_no, time_out, time_in`, DISTINCT will combine them if you don't distinguish them by `date`.

Comment: Can you also tell me the signif. of date. I dont get why that is used to find the accomplish flights

Comment: It's a column in the `pass_in_trip` table. It doesn't have any other significance.

Comment: but why is it used to find the accomplish flights, i dont really get why you have to join all these tables

Comment: I don't really understand your design. The `pass_in_trip` table is about passengers, why is the trip date in that table, not in the `trip` table?

Comment: This is an online sql question i am trying to solve. The schema wasnt designed by me, but i assume it relates more to passengers because it tells when they went on the trip. Since each table should have unique columns (variables), you can easily connect it with the Trip table to find the date of the trip.